# How to save html2canvas image to my project images folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html2canvas

I am not sure how to specify the path for the file to be save (like ../images/screenshot.png)I tried saving the image like

```
html2canvas($my-div, {
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
      location.href = img;
   }
});
```

This gets downloaded to my system downloads.How do I save this to the folder inside the project (want to specify the path I want to save the file)?

Comment: You have to send that image to server and process via PHP. `var img` will contain just image base64 string, nothing more

Comment: but why? I want to save that image in client side. Ok Let me put the question this way.. I want to share the screenshot taken using social sharing plugin.

Comment: My code to share image `window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
            'My Message',
            null,
            [image link here],
            null
        );`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some library like [Canvas2Image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) to download image. User will specify image path by it self (you don't know where to save it, because there may be no such directory as 'C:\Users{SomeUsername}\Downloads'

```
html2canvas($my-div, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        return Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried Canvas2Image and it saves the image to the system downloads. Even without using any library I can save the image to the downloads with the code `canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")` I want to save the image to the specific path in my project folder. Any help?

Comment: @Meroshini You have to specify where you wish to save that file. Maybe you have auto-save of some sort? Have you tried http://hongru.github.io/proj/canvas2image/index.html

Comment: Yeah thanks for the effort @Justinas. But I have to mention that path in code.. save should happen implicitly.  User should not choose the path to save.. The task is once the share button is clicked the current page will be captured and shared via user preferred social media.

Comment: @Meroshini So you want to capture some are and send that data to some social media website or save it to computer? What soc. media, what plugin...

Comment: Am using [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) to share. The code will look like `window.plugins.socialsharing.share( 'My Message', null, [image link here], null );` I can add the image link by saving it somewhere in my code (/images folder)

Comment: @Meroshini so again, you have to use your server PHP to save TO SERVER, not to user computer, and only than you can share that image.

Comment: yeah.. I couldn't do upvote as I dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this problem. The plugin that helped me to save canvas to image in my local storage is [canvas2image plugin from devgeeks](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin). Directly pass your canvas as parameter to the save function of plugin which will save that canvas as image to your local storage.

```
    html2canvas($my-div, {
    height: myDivHeight,
    width: 350,
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    proxy: "your url",
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
          console.log(msg) //path where image is saved
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        canvas // pass canvas as third parameter
      );
    }
  });
```

I used [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) library to captured the current screen and used canvas2Image plugin to save it to my local storage. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of screenshot upload

Step 01:

include html2canvas CDN inside your html file

Step 02:

```
  <form id="imgupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="imagename" id="imghidden">
    </form>

    <canvas id=img>
      <img src="....">
    </canvas> 

    <button id="imgupload"></button>
```

Step 03:

```
  $("#imgupload").click(function(){
  html2canvase($("#img"),{
  onrendered:function(canvas)
  {
   var canvasinfo=canvas;
   $(#imghidden).val(canvasinfo.toDataURL('image/png'));
   var formid=$("#imgupload")[0];
   var data=new FormData(formid);

   $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:"dataSave.php", 
               data:data,
               contentType: false,
               cache: false,
               processData:false,
               success:function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
               },error:function(error)
               {
                   console.log(error);
               }
           });
  }

});
});
```

Step 04:

Put this code inside the dataSave.php file

```
<?php
    $filteredData=substr($POST['imghidden'],strpos($_POST['imghidden'],',')+1);
    $DecodeData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    //Now you can upload image inside the folder
    $imgPath='img'.time().'.png';
    file_put_contents($imgPath,$DecodeData);

?>
```